# Error message trying to connect to the internet "Windows can't connect to the network"

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

When I try to connect to my internet Windows says, it can’t connect to this network. This error message persist about 30 minute then Windows connects. This happends every time after I start up, sleep, even when I disconnect. I'm using Windows 10, and I have Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 adapter. It was fine until I installed Ubuntu and then returned to Windows then it happened.

I've tried everything from resetting the router, setting static IP, updating the driver to formatting my computer. What else should I do?

Comment: Do you have the same issue using a LAN cable? Have you tried re-installing/updating the drivers?

Comment: i don't have an rj-45 port in my computer, though this happens only on my home router on other router i can connect without problem, and yes i tried to reinstall/update and i still have the problem

Comment: then I would look at your home router, because if it's your client, it would be the same issue on ALL routers.

Comment: I agree with @CustomX. I don't think installing Ubuntu or another OS can affect Windows 10 configuration. You say you have reset the router among other things. You have even formatted the computer so my guess is you messed up the router configuration or/and you haven't properly configured the new installation of Windows. But just my guess. Try live-booting from the Ubuntu USB/DVD and see whether you can connect. If you can, it's the new Windows configuration. If not, it's the router.

Comment: What is your computer model and which driver did you install?

Comment: @harrymc I have an asus vivobook s14 s410ua, and the driver version is 12.0.0.697

Comment: yes i its the router i've tried booting from live cd same problem, and when i connect to another network it works right away, but the problem stil persist even when reset the router, should i change it ?

Comment: Yes, trying another router of a different model might help in examining the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with my laptop connecting to my mobile hotspot. Oddly when I click on the error message, Windows tries to reconnect right away so it only takes a half minute instead of 10 minutes as it was in my case. It's only a work around but maybe it works in your case as well.